# Creating overlapping draggable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

On a button click event a new div is created. Once a div is created it becomes draggable thanks to the help of the jqueryui draggable [PLUGIN](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/). I am running into an issue that occurs when I try to stack a div on top of another. The latest created div element will stay on top and can’t be overlapped by any previously created div. Any suggestions or solutions of how I can stack divs not barred/limited to the latest div element creation? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/0wbnud4k/30/)

Jquery

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        text: $('textarea').val(),
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent'
        }
    }).addClass('placement');


    /** Contain draggable div **/
    $('.middle-side').parent().mousemove(function(e){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var relX = e.pageX - offset.left;
        var relY = e.pageY - offset.top;
        $('.placement').css({'top': relY + 30,'left': relX + 10, 'position': 'absolute'});
    })

});

/** Place a temporary dashed border on div after initial creation**/
$('.middle-side').on('click', function(e){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var relX = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var relY = e.pageY - offset.top;
    $('.placement').css({'top': relY,'left': relX, 'position': 'absolute' });
    $(this).off("mousemove").find('.placement').removeClass('placement')    
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter Text Here!"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Add Div with Text" />
<br/>
<div>
    <div class="middle-side empty"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep `z-index` of draggable layer more than the others one.
First add `position` and `z-index` properties to your `.draggable` elements in CSS:

```
.draggable {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background:#FFFFDD;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And in your JS:

```
// the counter
var z = 1;

$('<div />', {
    class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
    text: $('textarea').val(),
    appendTo: '.middle-side',
    draggable: {
        containment: 'parent',

        // whenever the drag start
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            // set the z-index one more
            $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
        }
    }
}).addClass('placement');
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/32/).