# Containing a draggable div to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working with jquery ui draggable library. On a button on click I am able to create and append text to a new div. But I am running into two problems: the created new divs do not stay contained to the parent div. In other words How can I keep the draggable divs inside parent div `container`? Second I have set a `z-index` in order to be able to overlap one div in top of another. Currently the latest created div stays on top. How can a make divs overlappable not depending on the element creation order? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/P9C7E/28/)

Jquery

```
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'ui-widget-content',
        appendTo: '.container',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
    <div href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span><br/><br/>
        <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your second problem, can you explain it more?

Comment: @ROX similar function to this [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589912/creating-overlapping-draggable-divs/25590022#25590022)

Comment: $('#drag1').draggable(
    {
        containment: "#ContainmentBox",...

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem, use `position` and `overflow` properties for your `.container` element:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/P9C7E/29/).

Comment: The issue is that it allows the draggable div to be slided into the container edge and it disappears. How can I avoid that disappearing of the draggable div?